# Eclipse - how to get the line which caused an exception?

Tags: eclipse, exception

I am getting some SQLExceptions in my Java 1.6- Oracle11g- JDBC (ie OJDBC6) code. But I am unable to see which line of code caused the problem.
How do I use Eclipse to find out which line of code was responsible for the problem ?

The output of my code -

```
Running main...
Exception- java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00911: invalid character
Exiting main...
```

Thanks.

PS- I don't think it is necessary to put the code here. I only want to know which line was responsible and fix the code myself. I am trying to take as little extra help as I can.

Comment: Could you please post your code where this exception occurs and related surrounding code.

Comment: Do you know how to connect eclipse to your container/webserver to do remote debugging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming exceptions are being caught somewhere in your main method? Wherever they are being caught do a `myException.printStackTrace()`. Or else just run your code with the debugger and go through line by line to see where it screws up.

Comment: Here is a decent looking tutorial on the Eclipse debugger : http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseDebugging/article.html

Answer (score 2):

You have some code, somewhere, that is following this pattern:

```
try 
    {
    ...
    }
catch (Exception err)
    {
    System.out.println("Exception- "+err);
    }
```

This is a bad pattern because, as you see, only the message of the exception is reported and the exception goes away.

Either use `err.printStackTrace(System.out)` (if you really want the output on stdout instead of stderr), or `err.printStackTrace()`.  ***Or***, just don't catch the exception at all and the JVM will print the entire stack trace.

The stack trace contains the classes, methods, file names and line numbers.  When the stack trace is printed out, Eclipse' console will turn the file name and line number into a hyperlink that you can just click to go to the source.

Comment: Yes, I see the lines that generated the error. Now, there are two types of lines here - 

1 - Lines from my code, ie lines whose code i can see.
2- Lines of code from oracle jdbc classes whose code i cannot see.

So, basically I will have to ignore lines of type 2 and focus only on type 1 ?

Comment: Yes - generally the problem is in your code, though sometimes the problem is actually in the library.  In this case of a SQL syntax error, the useful part is where in your program did the SQL code originate, and then to determine what is wrong with that SQL.